# Error with radio button in haml ruby rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I was working on a radio button feature in my `html.haml` file and the code is as below:

```
= form.input :keep_open, :as => :radio, :label => "Keep Reservation Open"
```

This creates the radio buttons as :

```
o keep Open
o keep closed
```

But when I try to check these radio buttons from outside the radio button area, they work. i.e the radio button gets clicked, so please let me know how to get rid of this.

It should only work when I click on the radio button, that's probably some attribute of the radio button which I have to add on to the above line of code, but that's very confusing.

Comment: Standard radio button behavior is to toggle when you click on the button OR the text.  Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: As Jim says, the Radio button will be marked checked if the label is clicked as well. In order to remove this behavior you will have to override your label settings so that the label `for="theRadioButton` does not have the same id as your radio button. However, consider the fact that this is happening by design for usability and accessibility purposes.

Comment: but the behaviour here is different, the radio button is getting selected even though if i click on empty space which is straigt alligned to the radio button, Example:
o Enabled                                                       {}
when i click at {} then the Enabled radio Button gets selected, where as the behaviour should be {When i click on radio button 'o' or either on text 'Enabled'  then it should be selected

Comment: That is probably happening because your other elements are wrapped within the `label` tag for your radio button. Can you post the HTML generated by your code?

Comment: I got the solution for this:
we have css file defined which would override the haml code, The css radio button width was 100% and hence blank spaces was occupied, thanks anyways for the hints